# How to get (DevExpress WPF) SpreadsheetControl cell value by searching an ID and show a specific cell value to a textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, spreadsheet, devexpress-wpf

I have searched everywhere but I don't know how can I achieve that task. I'm using DevExpress in Visual Studio (WPF Application). I want to search spreadsheet using an ID and select a specific cell value in the Row that should be appeared in the Second textbox. Any help will be appreciated.
Here's some code with button control,

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //textBox2.Text = book.Selection["7"];
        Worksheet worksheet = book.ActiveWorksheet;

        IEnumerable<Cell> searchResult = worksheet.Search(textBox1.Text);            
        textBox2.Text = worksheet.Rows[textBox1.Text].Search;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't have enough details. But try to find the workbook from code-behind (WorkBook)this.FindName("myWorkbook").ActiveWorkSheet. Otherwise provide more details error message, etc

Comment: Thanks for your response @silverfighter, I want to add data to a WPF SpreadSheetControl (SpreadSheet by DevExpress). I don't have any idea about Programming structure for copying a cell value using a TextBox. TextBox1 should search by ID and a specific cell value in the searched Row should appear in the TextBox2. Thanks again